# Sort string field that contains integers, decimals, and strings SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sorting, dynamic

I inherited a project that has a table that could contain a string, decimal, or integer.

I need to sort on this field.

Lets assume that I can (based off an id) grab only one type at a time, but to be sure, I want to still confirm the type before sorting and if it is not all the same type, just sort by string.

So the table could look like this.

`select id, fkID, myValue from myTable`

```
 id |fkID|myValue
____|____|_______
 1  |14  |abc
 2  |14  |ghi
 3  |14  |def

 4  |11  |2000
 5  |11  |1500
 6  |11  |10000

 7  |17  |110.04
 8  |17  |500.22
 9  |17  |100.99
```

Then say I could grab all of `fkID` 11. I would want it sorted

```
 5  |11  |1500
 4  |11  |2000
 6  |11  |10000
```

Or `fkID` 14 would be

```
 1  |14  |abc
 3  |14  |def
 2  |14  |ghi
```

I can not figure out how to tackle this problem but have tried using a Try_Parse to determine the value of the column.

Dynamic sql is fine if thats what works.

Comment: What's the database? Sybase, Informix, dBase, Ingres? Conversion clauses and functions differ quite a bit in different databases.

Comment: The database is Microsoft Sql Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you've inherited structure not handled well in sql-server or in any major database (reminds me of the over-normalized EAV and OTLT patterns).

You can:

1. Use try_convert to capture the decimal representations if they're available.
2. Use a windowed max to identify whether there are any non decimals.
3. Use a conditional statement using different versions of row_number to get your ordering.

Here it is in action:

```
declare @fkId int = 11;

select      t.*,
            ord = iif( 
                max(iif(decVal is null, 1, 0)) over() = 1, -- has any non decimals?
                row_number() over(order by myValue), -- string ordering
                row_number() over(order by decVal) -- decimal ordering
            )
from        @myTable t
cross apply (select decVal = try_convert(decimal(10,2), myValue)) ap
where       fkId = @fkId -- replace this with whatever.
order by    ord;
```

Comment: Amazing. Thanks for the information. Why did you choose to use `decimal(10,2)` rather than `float`? Perhaps it doesn't matter either.

Comment: It was arbitrary.  Matters depending on your needs.

Answer (score -1):

This answers the original version of the question.

For your examples, you would just use:

```
order by my_value
```

The order you have specified -- even for the numbers -- works with an alphabetical ordering.

Comment: Hey @Gordon_Linoff , I have updated the examples to include a number in which that would not work. Sometimes the numbers may be 90,000 and 100,000 which would no longer make regular string sorting work properly

Comment: yes @TheImpaler, I updated that entry so he hasn't updated his answer yet